# strange behavior in character string and pipe

Tags: c, string, pipe

I have a program:

```
    int main()
    {
      int* p_fd = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
      char buf[100];
      pipe(p_fd);
      write(p_fd[1],"hello", strlen("hello"));
      int n;
      n = read(p_fd[0],buf,100);
      //printf("n is: %d\n",n);                // this line is important!
      buf[n]="\0";                             // this line triggers warning。
      printf("%s\n",buf);
    }
```

when I comiple this file, I always get the warning:

```
[esolve@kitty temp]$ gcc -o temp temp.c
temp.c: In function ‘main’:
temp.c:38:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

and without this line `printf("n is: %d\n",n);`
the result is :

```
[esolve@kitty temp]$ ./temp
 hellon
```

with this line, I get the expected result:

```
    [esolve@kitty temp$ ./temp
    n is: 5
    hello
```

why the line is so important?
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
buf[n]="\0";
```

should be

```
buf[n]='\0';
```

`"\0"` is a *pointer* to a string literal but `buf` is a `char` array.  That's why the warning is about assigning a pointer to an integer.

You should only assign a `char` to an element of `buf`.  I presume you wanted to add a null terminator to your array; `'\0'` is a `char` with value 0 so provides this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
buf[n]="\0";
```

do

```
buf[n]='\0'; //with single quotes
```

Double quotes make it character string, but you want character.